# iOS app runs normally in debug mode but crashed in normal mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios8

**Summary: I'm developing an app. The strange thing is when I run it in debug mode(connect my device to Xcode and click run button), it acts normally. But when I run it in normal mode(Without connecting it to Xcode, open it normally like what a user will do), it crashed.**

Solution: please see the answer by @skyline75489 below, his answer saved my day! When you encounter this problem, try to reduce the size of the images.
Details:

Now I'm developing an iOS8 keyboard. In the init of the keyboard, there's something that seems to take a lot of memory. I think it's not the problem of the extension, it's the problem of the memory or setting.

```
for (int i = 0; i<=numberOfImagesInCurrentArray; i++) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[currentPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i.png",i]]];
    if (image) {
        [convertedArray addObject:image];

    }
}
```

Now the problem is when I'm in debug mode(When I connect my device to Mac and run the extension, and attach the extension to "Message" app), the extension runs perfectly even if the array contains 30 images. (takes 40M memory)

But when I run it in normal mode(open "Message", and click on the textfield), the extension crashed with only 15 images in that array, but when there're only about 10 images, it doesn't crash.

My question is : is this issue caused by memory issue? Or I set something wrong in the info.plist that causes the differences in debug mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've encountered the same problem. It's because of memory limitation of iOS 8 keyboard extension.

As for now, the memory limitation for a keyboard extension is around 30MB. If your extension takes 40M memory as you said, it will be immidiately killed by the OS on a real iOS device.

However, when debuging it, iOS seems to no longer limit the memory usage of it.

Comment: So how can I solve the issue except using less memory? If I have to load png from a directory, is there a way to limit the memory usage?

Comment: @NSError You can try images of lower resolution. Doesn't seem to have another way but to reduce memory usage. Or wait for iOS 8.2 which may (or may not) modify the limitaion.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to come up with some other ways.

Comment: @NSError I'm not a expert of image. Perhaps there is some way to impressively reduce the memory usage of storing images. Wish you luck.

Comment: Just want to thank you bro! You saved my day! You give me a perfect idea of how to do it. When I save the images, I reduce the size of the images proportionally. Doing this saves A LOT OF memory! Now, when I try to load 30 images, it only takes 30M memory and it doesn't crash anymore!. THANK YOU!!!